# How can a Flask decorator have arguments?

Tags: python, decorator, flask

I implemented a decorator in the same way as here
[How to make a python decorator function in Flask with arguments (for authorization)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13896650/how-to-make-a-python-decorator-function-in-flask-with-arguments-for-authorizati)
but problem still unsolved...

I have this function with decorators

```
@blueprint.route('<var>')
@blueprint.my_decorator(var)
def function(var):
    do stuff
```

and I get this error

```
NameError: global name 'var' is not defined
```

How do I solve this?

---

**Update**

The blueprint is a class inheriting the Blueprint class.
So I implemented the method

```python
def my_decorator(self, fn):
    @wraps(fn)
    def decorator(*args, **kwargs):
        value = kwargs['value']
        # do stuff with value
        return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    return decorator
```

but still the value is an uknown key...

Comment: You should accept the answer, if it correctly answers your question. :)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Decorators are executed at import time, they're essentially syntactic sugar:

```
@foo(bar)
def baz():
    return 'w00t!'
```

is equivalent to

```
def baz():
   return 'w00t!'
baz = foo(bar)(baz)
```

So in the example above variable `bar` must exist in the global scope of this module before it is passed to the decorator as argument.  That's what the error you've got tells you.

---

**Update**

Based on the discussion below, the code in the question should intercept the value passed to view function and do something with it.  Here's an example that demonstrates it:

```
from functools import wraps
from flask import Flask, abort

app = Flask(__name__)

def foobar(fn):
    @wraps(fn)
    def decorated_view(*args, **kwargs):
        value = kwargs['value']
        # Do something with value...
        if value == 'foobar':
            abort(400)
        return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    return decorated_view

@app.route('/<value>')
@foobar
def view(value):
    return value
```

Comment: so how can I make the var to be equivalent to '<var>'?

Comment: Not sure if I'm following you. Could you please explain what you're trying to achieve with your own decorator?

Comment: Im trying to edit some html elements based on the url variable <var>.

Comment: Oh, I think I understand now. And no, this is not how you do this. The argument decorator takes is passed at the function definition time. If you want to intercept the argument that your view function gets, you need to do this inside your decorator code. I'll update my answer with working example to demonstrate this.

Comment: Thank you for your update but I must be doing sth wrong... :-/ I updated the question.

Comment: Note that in my example I'm accessing `kwargs['value']`, because I set this name in the route as well, i.e. `@app.route('/<value>')`. If you want it to work with different routes, you need to inspect what keys kwargs dictionary has, e.g. by calling `kwargs.keys()` or looking for some specific keys `if 'foo' in kwargs: ...`.

Comment: this does not answer the question , there is no argument passed into the decorator ...in the example from @d3m he needs to pass `var` .

Comment: Thanks for this - just what I was looking for

Comment: This doesn't answer the question as the decorator doesn't take any arguments.

Comment: To understand better decorator and flask, this article can be handy https://medium.com/@nguyenkims/python-decorator-and-flask-3954dd186cda

Answer (score 2):

What worked for me was adding a decorator on top of the existing one and not using the `@wrap(fn)`. There might be a way to achieve this using the `@wrap(fn)` as well, but here is an alternative solution.

The decorator:

```
def decorator(arg):
    def inner_decorator(fn):
        def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
            value = kwargs['key']
            return fn(*args, **kwargs)

        if arg == 'foo'
           return wrapped
        else:
           return ('Uknown argument', HTTPStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
    
    return inner_decorator
```

The function where it's used:

```
@decorator('foo')
def function(var):
    # do something
```