# Efficient way of handling XHR request in Python Flask

Tags: python, flask

Currently I am using following way of views to determine if request is **AJAX / XHR**. Accordingly I am returning json data and rendering the template file in Flask. This working perfectly so for in my application.

```
from flask import request, render_template, jsonify
@cinemascope.route('/cinema')
def cinema():
    if request.is_xhr:
        cinema = Cinema.query.all()
        return jsonify({'cinema_scope': cinema})
    return render_template('cinema.html')
```

But I see this way little problematic as my application might many more @app.routes and every time I will have to repeat the code (if clause) so its loosing upon the maintainability aspect.

I am thinking about the two options here -

**Option # 1** - Writing a simple function to wrap the if clause from above route.

**Option # 2** - writing a decorator which will determine the request and accordingly it can be called from route - in a way decorator will handle the **redundant** part of code. I dont know too much about writing custom decorators so far though after reading little about it seems to be the best option.

Any further direction in adopting any of above approaches will be appreciated.

**Basically I want to know the way - so I can avoid `if clause` part of code in each and every @app.route.**

Comment: Please let me know if any queries.

Comment: I welcome -ve ratings on the posts but -ve rating with respective comments is much appreciated as that will allow me make required changes in the question - this will not only help me but also to the community members would like to answer the questions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I refered - from http://justindonato.com/notebook/template-or-json-decorator-for-flask.html

This is what my decorator looks like

```
from functools import wraps

def xhr_request_check(template=None):

    def decorator_request_parser(f):
        @wraps(f)
        def decorator_request(*args, **kwargs):
            func_data = f(*args, **kwargs)
            if request.is_xhr or not template:
                return jsonify(func_data)
            else:
                return render_template(template, **func_data)
        return decorator_request
    return decorator_request_parser
```

**In my view I have written**

```
from flask import request, render_template, jsonify
@catalog.route('/cinema')
@xhr_request_check('cinema.html')
def cinema():
    cinema = Cinema.query.all()
    return {'cinema_scope': cinema}
```

Now I just needs to add **`@xhr_request_check('cinema.html')`** to each route and it is working perfectly.

**Please let me know if any one would even better solution from code optimization perspective.**

Comment: Please let me know if there could be still any improvements in the code as still I am new in writing decorators and using it effectively.

Answer (score 2):

The way of doing this would be to create a decorator, which are essentially functions which take a function as an input and return a function as an output.  They are not specific to flask, but python in general.

Here is an example for flask:
[How to make a python decorator function in Flask with arguments (for authorization)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13896650/how-to-make-a-python-decorator-function-in-flask-with-arguments-for-authorizati)

Comment: Thanks John - link sent by is helpful to me. :)

Answer (score 0):

`is_xhr` is deprecated, but you could check on the [Accepts header](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45047544/450917) instead.